# Access the JS this from scala.js

Tags: scala.js

I need to implement a call from scala.js a method like:

```
sigma.classes.graph.addMethod('getNodesCount', function() {
  return this.nodesArray.length;
});
```

that is the way that bring the library in JS to access the internal array nodesArray of the class sigma.clasess.graph. I tried something like

```
trait GraphClassesJS extends js.Object {
  def addMethod(name:String,handler: js.Function0[Any]):Unit=js.native
}
```

I try to call with

```
s.classes.graph.addMethod("getNodesCount",()=>js.ThisFunction.nodesArray.length)
```

but I get

```
 value nodesArray is not a member of object scala.scalajs.js.ThisFunction
[error]     s.classes.graph.addMethod("getNodesCount",()=>js.ThisFunction.nodesArray.length)
```

How can I do it?
Thanks
Reynaldo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misunderstood the nature of `js.ThisFunction`. It is not a syntactical replacement for `this` from JS. It is an alternative hierarchy of types for functions that take `this` as an explicit parameter.

The definition you need is almost what you wrote, but replacing `js.Function0` by `js.ThisFunction0`, and specifying the type of `Thing` which contains the field `nodesArray` (maybe `Graph`?):

```
trait Thing extends js.Object {
  def nodesArray: js.Array[Node]
}

trait GraphClassesJS extends js.Object {
  def addMethod(name: String, handler: js.ThisFunction0[Thing, Any]): Unit = js.native
}
```

Now, you can call it like this:

```
s.classes.graph.addMethod("getNodesCount", thiz => thiz.nodesArray.length)
```

Now `thiz` is the exact equivalent of the JS `this`. Its type is inferred to be `Thing`.

Comment: I'm closer but dont compile yet. I have:

Comment: @gilcu2 It seems your comment was cut earlier than intended.