# How to implement a jQuery Plugin using Scala.js

Tags: scala.js

The [Scala.js documentation](https://www.scala-js.org/doc/interoperability/facade-types.html) has a nice example on how to implement a jQuery facade which also supports chaining:

```
@js.native
trait JQueryGreenify extends JQuery {
  def greenify(): this.type = ???
}

object JQueryGreenify {
  implicit def jq2greenify(jq: JQuery): JQueryGreenify =
   jq.asInstanceOf[JQueryGreenify]
}
```

However as far as I understood it, this example assumes that the `greenify` plugin has been implemented in Javascript already. E.g. like

```
$.fn.greenify = function() {
  this.css( "color", "green" );
  return this;
}
```

How would this plugin be implemented in Scala.js?

Comment: I honestly don't know if anybody's tried to do so yet.  It's certainly possible to do -- as a rule, if it can be done in JavaScript, it should be doable in Scala.js -- but people writing in Scala.js have mostly been writing Scala-centric libraries.  So the short answer is, "you'd implement it the same way you would in JavaScript", but I suspect there's some unexplored ground in the details of how best to do that...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There two ways to define a "jQuery plugin" in Scala.js. The first one is a safe and idiomatic Scala-esque way, but is only for consumption by other Scala.js code. The second is a bit ugly, but it can be used by JavaScript code.

### For Scala.js

In Scala, and in Scala.js, the patch-the-prototype thing that actual jQuery plugins do is discouraged. Instead, we use *implicit classes*:

```scala
implicit class JQueryGreenify(val self: JQuery) extends AnyVal {
  def greenify(): self.type = {
    self.css("color", "green")
    self
  }
}
```

And then you can simply do

```scala
jQuery("#some-element").greenify()
```

when you have `JQueryGreenify` in scope (as an import, typically).

This method does not pollute the actual prototype of jQuery objects. It is a pure-Scala abstraction. It is clean and safe, but that means it cannot be used by JavaScript code.

### For JavaScript

If you need to call `greenify` from JavaScript, you actually need to add a function property on the `jQuery.fn` object. Since the function needs to use the `this` parameter, we have to explicitly ascribe it to a `js.ThisFunction` (see also [Access the JS this from scala.js](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29951782/1829647)):

```scala
js.Dynamic.global.jQuery.fn.greenify = { (self: JQuery) =>
  self.css("color", "green")
  self
}: js.ThisFunction
```

which is basically a transliteration of the original JavaScript code from the question.